# Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " 7.16.3 when passing float from read command

Tags: bash, read, floating-point

I am trying to automate software update with bash script. When I am passing version number e.g 7.16.3 I get following error: ") Syntax error Invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

I could not find any answer which related when passing value from `read` command. My code look like below:

```
DATE=`date +'%Y%m%d'`
BSI_SETUP=/opt/bsi/source/setup/elk_${DATE}
OLD_VERSION_FILEBEAT=`/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat version| awk '{print $3 }' 2>/dev/null`
OLD_VERSION_METRICBEAT=`/usr/share/metricbeat/bin/metricbeat version| awk '{print $3 }' 2>/dev/null`
MY_HOME=~

read -p 'Enter filebeat & metricbeat version: ' NEW_VERSION_BEATS 
read -p 'Enter CSC environmet: ' CSC_ENV

if [[ ${NEW_VERSION_BEATS} -ne ${OLD_VERSION_FILEBEAT} ]]; then # I get error here
   sudo yum install -y $BSI_SETUP/filebeat-*.rpm 2>/dev/null
else
   echo "Filebeat is up-to-date"   
fi

if [[ ${NEW_VERSION_BEATS} -ne ${OLD_VERSION_METRICBEAT} ]]; then # and here 
   sudo yum install -y $BSI_SETUP/metricbeat-*.rpm 2>/dev/null
else
   echo "Metricbeat is up-to-date"      
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be using string inequality `!=` instead of numeric inequality `-ne` in this case?

Comment: @Quasímodo yes, but how we do call it?

Comment: @steeldriver I must try it. Thanks for idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-ne` does a numeric comparison, while `7.16.3` is not a number. (Even if it's called a "version number".) As it happens, as far as Bash is concerned, neither would `7.16` be, since Bash only deals with integers. The error is actually clearer within Bash's `[ .. ]`:

```
$ [ 7.16.3 -ne 7.16.3 ]
bash: [: 7.16.3: integer expression expected
```

Use `[ "$a" = "$b" ]`, or `[[ $a == "$b" ]]` for string equality comparison, `!=` for inequality. (`[ "$a" == "$b" ]` works in Bash, but isn't standard.)

OTOH, if your error really looks like that, with the `")` in front, it's due to a carriage return in the value.

```
$ var=$'7.16\r'
$ [[ $var -ne 7.16 ]]
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".16
```

In that case, check that your input doesn't come from a Windows text file, or use something like `var=${var%$'\r'}` to remove the CR.

Comment: [ "$a" != "$b" ] also possible?

Comment: @codehunter-py, yeah, see edit, just realized it was `-ne` and not `-eq` there...